# context:component-scan not working in junit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I added all the base-package in my applicationContext.xml, but still i is showing `noBeanDefinitionException`.

> applicationContext.xml

```
  <!-- Autowiring -->

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.paymentech.developercenter.services"/>

        <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-fragment-mybatisMOCK.xml" />
```

> DispathcherServlet-servlet.xml

```
   <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" /> 

      <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"/>
```

> FaqControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml" })
    @WebAppConfiguration("WEB-INF/web.xml")

    public class FaqControllerTest {
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext context;

        @Autowired
        private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

        @Before
        public void init() throws ServletException, IOException {
            SpringTestConfiguration.init(context, dispatcherServlet);

        }
```

> Error:-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'integratorSolutionController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solutionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'integratorSolutionService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solutionStatusService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'solutionStatusService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solutionStatusMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.paymentech.developercenter.persistence.isg.mappers.SolutionStatusMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'integratorSolutionController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solutionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'integratorSolutionService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solutionStatusService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'solutionStatusService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solutionStatusMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.paymentech.developercenter.persistence.isg.mappers.SolutionStatusMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

And That means, Spring cannot created an object whom the name is "solutionStatusService".

**Why**: because one of its dependencies named "solutionStatusMapper" cannot be created by Spring.

**The root cause**: You didn't add a component-scan which will scan your persistence layer represented by "com.paymentech.developercenter.persistence" **OR** you added it and you didn't add @Component above "solutionStatusMapper". Otherwise, Spring will see it.